# how do I know a telegram bot is mine?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I visited my telegram desktop after a while. in my group and channel list (or my chat list), I see some telegram bots... Some have good names (take like job_bot). First, my question is if the bot name or id is unique?
Second,I remember I created one of them. However, I see I have no control to delete it or see myself as its creator! Moreover, its information is like other bots in my list! I wonder if I created the rest or not! In general the question is how can I know if a bot is mine, and what control do I have over it? because the information I see gives me no control or clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of bots you have ownership of you can contact @BotFather and type `/mybots`.

A bot's username (stating with `@` sign, ending with "bot") is unique.

It's name (the name displayed in your contacts list after adding a bot) can be set to whatever you wish. It's not unique.